# How can I tell npm to install the latest bleeding edge master branch using npm install?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install a package using npm. I want to install the latest master branch, not any of the releases. In my package.json I currently have:

```
'packageName': '0.4.x',
```

Is there a way to tell npm to pull the latest master branch when I run `npm install packageName` rather than one of the repo's releases?

Something like `'packageName': 'master'` in my package.json (though this doesn't work).

Comment: If there's a `packageName@1.0.0` version in the npm registry you can install it with `npm install packageName@latest`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm install packageName` only lets you install things that are uploaded to npm.

What I needed to do was to fork the repo myself and create a new release in my own git repo. Then I can use:

`npm install git+https://github.com/myGitAccount/my-repo.git`

and it will install that latest release.

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
npm install git+https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script.git
```

or for those without git

```
 npm install http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/tarball/master
```

Information is from [github](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/2577)